# WebView playing local HTML with HTML5 Videos from SD Card, Android Nougat

Tags: android-webview

Found quite a view threads, none did help. Either deprecated methods or just not working. Need videos to play Fullscreen or as part of a website.

Important is I can play youtube Files online in an iframe. Is there a way to load the videos over a small webserver?

Videos are either black, or on startup shown with a white play triangle but wont play.

```
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
                //webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
                webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
                webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
                webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
                webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
                webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
                webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);

String html = "<html><head></head><body><video id=\"video\" ><source src=\""+ "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/xxxx/files/cache.work/myvideo.mp4"+"\" type=\"video/mp4\"></source></video></body></html>";

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html","utf-8", "");
```

errors:

```
/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
```